# subform display records for today's date as default

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Main form and a sub form. In the main form I would like to have a text box with today's date in it (date=()) called txt_today. To the left and right of this box I have two other command buttons for next and previous. I would like these buttons to change txt_today to either the next day or previous day and in the subform below (sub_form_Dailys) to return the date.

As per accomplishing this, is it best to do with a query? i.e. onload filter to only show today's records, when the user clicks previous or next it queries tbl_tasks and filter by the field 'DailyTasks' or should I use VBA...What approach would be best? Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the *DefaultValue* property to: `=Date()`

The buttons could do in the *Click event*:

```
Me!PreviousDate.Value = DateAdd("d", -1, Date)
```

respectively

```
Me!NextDate.Value = DateAdd("d", 1, Date)
```

For filtering the subform, use the *MasterLinkFields* and *ChildLinkFields*.

Have a (hidden) textbox on the main form, named *FilterDate* also with a default value of =Date().
 Then specify:

```
MasterLinkFields: [FilterDate]
ChildLinkFields: [YourDateFieldOnTheSubform]
```

Expand the button click events to hold these lines as well:

```
Me!FilterDate.Value = DateAdd("d", -1, Date)
```

respectively

```
Me!FilterDate.Value = DateAdd("d", 1, Date)
```

The subform will filter automatically.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply :)